# NSApplicationDelegate class design

Tags: cocoa

I have created my first complex OS X application. While working on it, I've had some doubts about how I use the class that implements the `NSApplicationDelegate` protocol (the class Xcode creates by default for Cocoa applications, i.e. `MyApplicationAppDelegate.m/h`).

In many tutorials (and books), I see that people create an `AppController` class to manage main or generic application tasks. I prefer to add my generic tasks directly into `MyApplicationAppDelegate` and create specific controllers depending on the modules I need to manage.

For example, I add into `MyApplicationAppDelegate` every `IBAction` used to open other windows (i.e. opening a preference panel), every function that isn't strictly connected with a specific module/controller and `IBOutlet`s for the main interface. In `MyApplicationAppDelegate` I also add every reference to controllers used in my application. That's essentially about it.

I'm really confused because I'm not sure whether or note this is good design. Has `MyApplicationAppDelegate` been designed for some other purpose?

I would like any suggestions and if possible any articles you might know of about design patterns for Cocoa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode used not to create an application delegate class in the Cocoa Application template by default.

I believe Apple only introduced the automatic creation of an `<AppName>_AppDelegate` class with their project template fairly recently, maybe in version 3.2 or so.

This is why many older books and tutorials have you create an `AppController` class, because the old project template did not create one for you.

You are free to use the `<AppName>_AppDelegate` as your main controller class, and the reason Apple adds it to their template is that so many developers use the `NSApplicationDelegate` object as their main application controller.

An excellent resource to learn more about design patterns in Cocoa is the book appropriately called [Cocoa Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321535022).